# Why was this homework question (that seems to follow the guidelines for homework questions) closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, closed-questions

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35641154/trying-to-calculate-how-long-it-takes-to-pay-off-a-loan) was put on hold shortly after it was asked.

While it was not the best question in the world, it did a pretty good job of meeting the [guidelines for homework questions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10811/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions).

1. The questioner had made an honest effort to solve the problem, and it included a partially working program that demonstrated the effort.
2. The question listed three specific issues the program was having.
3. The question admitted it was a homework question.

What aspects of the "Asking about homework" guidelines does this question not adhere to?

If it does adhere to the guidelines, but still should be closed, how should the guidelines be changed to reflect the *real* reason(s) it was closed?

Comment: Because it's a big code dump that basically says, "I don't know what I'm doing, what should I do?"  It's also got two questions, too broad.  It's a poor question, and we shouldn't be wasting time answering it.  That's why it's closed.

Comment: Also, it's too localized, but that's not a close reason anymore.  The title describes the homework problem, not the problem they're having, and the body only describes what has to be done, not a specific problem with the code.

Comment: The question does not really follow the guidelines anyways, but more importantly, as George's answer below points out, the "guidelines for homework questions" are necessary but not sufficient for a good, answerable, question.

Answer (score 18):

The question as written does not meet our guidelines for staying open. Here's what it needs to be re-opened:

1. The Title should reflect the programming problem at hand.  Would a user search "Trying to calculate how long it takes to pay off a loan" if they had the same problem the OP has? **No**.

   In this case, the programming problem is their loop doesn't terminate.  That's an articulable programming problem that other users would search for.
2. They pasted their entire homework code instead of reproducing the problem with just the section that didn't terminate.  We don't want the whole problem, we just want the section that has the issue.  If *the whole code* is the problem, then that's a bit broad for us.  A reproduced example with just their loop variables is required here.
3. They articulate two separate issues with their homework assignment -- it almost feels like they're looking for a tutor.  Tutoring takes more than a few paragraphs.

These problems are not insurmountable; but until the user (or an enterprising editor) fixes them, it should remain closed.

Comment: _" We don't want the whole problem, we just want the section that has the issue."_ Really? You want to make that code youself?

Comment: @Qwertiy I don't understand your point. Please elaborate.

Comment: If you have a fragment of the program and going to check how it works, you have to write the rest of the program youself. If you have the whole program, you can just copy it. Yes, the asker should shorten the code if he can, but I do not think that posting of a code fragment instead of the program is a good idea in most cases.

Comment: @Qwertiy Why would you need the rest of the program if the fragment completely recreates the problem? That's the point of creating a minimal example. It should be minimal, but still recreate the problem so that we don't have to recreate the program.

Comment: @KevinB, why do we have code snippets? Why is it good to provide link to the fiddle in addition to the code? All these things contain full enought code, which you can touch, not just a fragment.

Comment: Those should also only contain a minimal fragment that recreates the problem, not the whole program. We (answerers) do not want to wade through 50 lines of code to fix a problem that could be recreated with 10.

Comment: @Qwertiy We have code snippets so that people can post *minimal* complete reproducible examples.  Why are you so intent on having code that is entirely superfluous, and accomplishes nothing but wasting the time of everyone reading it and detracting from the actual problem being asked about?

Comment: @Servy, no. I agree that the example should be minimal. But in the same time I want it to be _complete_. Not just a piece of code, but a "minimal complete reproducible example" as you said.

Comment: @Qwertiy Yes, so then why are you complaining about people asking for a minimal complete example by saying that they're asking for an incomplete example.  Nobody is asking for that.  They're saying that superfluous code should be removed, as in code not needed to provide a complete example.

Comment: @Servy, ok then I misunderstood the answer.